# VBA to multiply based on cell value, by cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pricing sheet which will import a CSV BOM from Creo into a new worksheet, I have that part sorted. The problem is the next part i want...

We have different values in column 'G' which are for the different materials e.g: 'MS', 'SS', 'ANGLE', 'PURCHASED'

The issue I have is creating a 'total cost' in column 'J' which is based on the material in 'G'. If the value is "MS" then the value in Column 'J' should be quantity x unit mass x material cost.

'Quantity' is the value in column C, 'unit mass' is the value in column E and 'material cost' is always cell H5 in worksheet named 'MASTER' (this is where the total cost column J should be driven from)

```
Sub subMultiply()

    For Each Cel In Range("G2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cel.Value = "MS" Then
            Cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cel.Offset(0, -2).Value * ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MASTER).Range(H5).Value * Cel.Offset(0, -4).Value
        ElseIf Cel.Value = "PURCHASED" Then
            Cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cel.Offset(0, -3).Value * ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MASTER).Range(H6).Value * Cel.Offset(0, -4).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error/problem? Should `MASTER` and `H5` and `H6` be within quotes?

Comment: Take a look at `vlookup` function

Comment: The problem is it will not work... doesn't add any values to the cell in column J?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'''

```
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For lRow = lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")

        With .Cells(lRow, "G")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value Like ("*MS*") Then Cells(lRow, "D").Value = Cells(lRow, "E").Value * ws2.Range("H5").Value
```

'''
I was able to add another If statement for each type of material

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the [select case](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/select-case.html) function

SOmething like :

```
Select Case Cells(i, 7)

    Case Is = "MS"
        Cells(i, 10) = 3

    Case Is = "SS"
        Cells(i, 10) = 5

    Case Is = "ANGLE"
        Cells(i, 10) = 8

    Case Is = "PURCHASED"
        Cells(i, 10) = 11
End Select
```

Instead of the numbers (3,5,8 and11) I used for my test, you can use whatever you want.

You can use the [sheets function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets) to select sheets : 
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(5,8) is H5 on the Master Sheets. 
Ex : `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Select`

Comment: Thanks, i need to refer to the cell in the master worksheet, how can i incorporate that into the multiplication?